# How to get UUID?

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth, uuid, android-bluetooth

Some time ago I started developing to Android.

I'm trying to create a `BluetoothServerSocket`.

I have this code:

```
tmp = mBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME, MY_UUID);
```

`NAME` is the name of my server (I can give here what i want) or not?

And I don't known what is `MY_UUID`. Where can I get `MY_UUID` from?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the UUID by utilizing the `getUuids()` method of the `BluetoothDevice` class. See this excellent thread that describes this very process, along with examples and the resulting output:

[Android - Get Bluetooth UUID for this device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19630810/android-get-bluetooth-uuid-for-this-device)