# What should my UUID be?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm relatively new to Android and am creating a Bluetooth App on a Nexus 9 that will connect to a Bluetooth device application my coworker has written on an Arduino processor.  I'm following this doc, which is very helpful:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html

However, to connect as a client I have to use this code, which uses this MY_UUID symbol.

```
      // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the server code
        tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
```

In the text the doc says: "The UUID passed here must match the UUID used by the server device when it opened its BluetoothServerSocket (with listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(String, UUID)). Using the same UUID is simply a matter of hard-coding the UUID string into your application and then referencing it from both the server and client code."

This is confusing to me... does it mean it must match a UUID specified in the Arduino firmware?? My coworker who wrote the firmware doesn't know what that would be.  When I sniff his firmware advertising, it has ID "RNBT-DFBC", but when I use that as a UUID I get an exception :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: RNBT-DFBC is not a valid Bluetooth address
```

And none of the sample Bluetooth projects I've looked at seem to explain the basis of this UUID value, they're just "magic numbers."

So... what on earth do I use as the parameter for my createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord() function?  I feel like I am misunderstanding this, because a Bluetooth client cant possibly generally have such "intimate" knowledge of a server it wants to connect to.  So sorry if it's a dumb question, but any help is appreciated.

Comment: read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632524/how-to-find-the-uuid-of-serial-port-bluetooth-device), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964342/android-how-do-bluetooth-uuids-work), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19630810/android-get-bluetooth-uuid-for-this-device) and many others before posting a question to avoid dublications

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088474/how-can-i-get-the-uuid-of-my-android-phone-in-an-application) is a nice way that tells you how to get UUID for your app.

[image: UUID]

Answer (score 0):

You should use a pre-shared UUID that both your device and the Arduino device knows. For example:

```
public static final java.util.UUID MY_UUID
        = java.util.UUID.fromString("DEADBEEF-0000-0000-0000-000000000000");
```

The String is in a format according to [RFC 4122](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt). You can find more information about the specifics for Android in the [Android UUID documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/UUID.html) .

Comment: This is the crux of the confusion to me... how is it possible that this is required if my coworker was able to write a working Bluetooth server WITHOUT specifying a UUID -- there is nothing to "share".  In fact, I have downloaded "Bluetooth Terminal" on my Nexus and I am able to connect to his Arduino.  What UUID is it using??