# Unable to get UUID of a device

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-ble

I am trying to get UUID, major, and minor of a BLE device and show it in listview, but every single time my  parseUUIDs()  is returning an empty list.
I have tried other methods also, but i'm still not close to it. 
If someone among you has extracted an UUID from a scanrecord his experience would be welcomed.

Manifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.aoa.ble_scan">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le"  android:required="true" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    BluetoothManager btManager;
    BluetoothAdapter btAdapter;
    BluetoothLeScanner btScanner;
    Button startScanningButton;
    Button stopScanningButton;
    TextView peripheralTextView;
    private final static int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION = 1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        peripheralTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.PeripheralTextView);
        peripheralTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

        startScanningButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.StartScanButton);
        startScanningButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startScanning();
            }
        });

        stopScanningButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.StopScanButton);
        stopScanningButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                stopScanning();
            }
        });
        stopScanningButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        btManager = (BluetoothManager)getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        btAdapter = btManager.getAdapter();
        btScanner = btAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();


        if (btAdapter != null && !btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableIntent,REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }

        // Make sure we have access coarse location enabled, if not, prompt the user to enable it
        if (this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("This app needs location access");
            builder.setMessage("Please grant location access so this app can detect peripherals.");
            builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
            builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION);
                }
            });
            builder.show();
        }
    }



    public BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback wleScanCallback = new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLeScan(BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice, int i, byte[] bytes) {

             List<UUID> temp = new ArrayList();
              temp = parseUUIDs(bytes);
             if(!temp.isEmpty())
             {
                 for ( UUID s : temp ) {

                     Log.d("UUID: ", s.toString());
                 }
             }
             else
             {
                 Log.d("temp ", bluetoothDevice.getAddress());
             }
        }
    };
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION: {
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    System.out.println("coarse location permission granted");
                } else {
                    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    builder.setTitle("Functionality limited");
                    builder.setMessage("Since location access has not been granted, this app will not be able to discover beacons when in the background.");
                    builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                    builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                        }

                    });
                    builder.show();
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }


    public void startScanning() {
        System.out.println("start scanning");
        peripheralTextView.setText("");
        startScanningButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        stopScanningButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                btAdapter.startLeScan(wleScanCallback);
            }
        });
    }

    public void stopScanning() {
        System.out.println("stopping scanning");
        peripheralTextView.append("Stopped Scanning");
        startScanningButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        stopScanningButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                btAdapter.stopLeScan(wleScanCallback);
            }
        });
    }
    private List<UUID> parseUUIDs(final byte[] advertisedData) {
        List<UUID> uuids = new ArrayList<UUID>();

        int offset = 0;
        while (offset < (advertisedData.length - 2)) {
            int len = advertisedData[offset++];
            if (len == 0)
                break;

            int type = advertisedData[offset++];
            switch (type) {
                case 0x02: // Partial list of 16-bit UUIDs
                case 0x03: // Complete list of 16-bit UUIDs
                    while (len > 1) {
                        int uuid16 = advertisedData[offset++];
                        uuid16 += (advertisedData[offset++] << 8);
                        len -= 2;
                        uuids.add(UUID.fromString(String.format("%08x-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", uuid16)));
                    }
                    break;
                case 0x06:// Partial list of 128-bit UUIDs
                case 0x07:// Complete list of 128-bit UUIDs
                    // Loop through the advertised 128-bit UUID's.
                    while (len >= 16) {
                        try {
                            // Wrap the advertised bits and order them.
                            ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(advertisedData, offset++, 16).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
                            long mostSignificantBit = buffer.getLong();
                            long leastSignificantBit = buffer.getLong();
                            uuids.add(new UUID(leastSignificantBit,
                                    mostSignificantBit));
                        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                            // Defensive programming.
                            //Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
                            continue;
                        } finally {
                            // Move the offset to read the next uuid.
                            offset += 15;
                            len -= 16;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    offset += (len - 1);
                    break;
            }
        }
        return uuids;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19630810/android-get-bluetooth-uuid-for-this-device

Comment: BluetoothAdapter.startLeScan() is deprecated as of API 21.  You might want to consider refactoring to use BluetoothLeScanner.startScan() and see if that works any better.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#startLeScan(android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback)